# Windows batch assign a var to another var

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

In my scipt i'm getting a string from a file and i would like this string to be interpreted as a var:

```
for /f %%G in (..\..\outrep.txt) do SET AUTOIMPORTDIR=%%G
```

In my outrep.txt file I have: `%USERPROFILE%`

So I would like `AUTOIMPORTDIR` equals to `C:\Documents and Settings\myUser`
and it's actually equals to `%USERPROFILE%`

What can i do to interpret this string as a Variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation you can use one more instance of `FOR /F` to evaluate the string  `%USERPROFILE%` using the option to execute the `ECHO` command:

```
FOR /F %%G IN (..\..\outrep.txt) DO
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%H IN ('ECHO %%G') DO SET AUTOIMPORTDIR=%%H
```

Important detail: the `tokens=*` option is necessary if the value you want to fetch includes spaces or tabs.

Comment: With those lines I have a syntax error, I tried to play with it to make the error disappear whitout any success.
Edit: now it's ok, just added the second for loop into () and it works like a charm!